# Buttons are not being created

Tags: jquery, html

I am following a pdf book to learn jQuery. The following code should create 2 buttons according to the book, but in my case, it just creates the simple text of it and not the button. I have re-checked the book to see if I am missing anything.

I am newbie so this seems to be a stupid question to you experts.

Code:

```
 <div id="switcher">
<div class="label">Style Switcher</div>
<div class="button" id="switcher-large">Increase Text Size</div>
<div class="button" id="switcher-small">Decrease Text size</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't make anything by itself. Can you post the jQuery code?

Comment: This is a complete code that was given there and below was the output (page having buttons).either they might not mention some code that will make the buttons.

Comment: Are you working with something else too? Some other scripts or files? This code by itself just shows three lines of text.

Comment: Nice; you've got three types of suggestions below to make a button :) The HTML way, the CSS way and the jQuery way... :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make it "look" like a button yourself. The easiest way to do this, is obviously through CSS.

```
.button {
background-color:red;
width:100px;
height:30px;
color:white;
padding:4px;
margin:10px;
}
.button:hover {
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

This could be one very basic way of doing things.

Comment: You might be missing a `width` proporty. Else the `<div>` will be default 100 % wide.

Answer (score 1):

You are just giving them class attributes on a div tag. Button is created by a button tag. Here is how you do it.

```
<div id="switcher">
    <div class="label">Style Switcher</div>
    <button class="button" id="switcher-large">Increase Text Size</button>
    <button class="button" id="switcher-small">Decrease Text size</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery UI, then you need to apply the button via javascript:

```
$(".button").button();
```

Answer (score 0):

By jQuery the `wrapInner` function can convert the text into a button, if that is what you need:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="switcher">
  <div class="label">Style Switcher</div>
  <div class="button" id="switcher-large">Increase Text Size</div>
  <div class="button" id="switcher-small">Decrease Text size</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('.button').wrapInner('<button />');

});
```

Of course you need to add something more - some `onClick` event to do, what you intent to do, or maybe by some other jQuery that executes, when the button is clicked, e.g. `$(button').on("click",function() {...`

http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/